# Returning the sum of all digits in int that are divisible by 2 c++

Tags: c++, recursion

I need to sum all digits in an int that are divisible by 2 using recursion. This is what i have so far. If my int is "4544", when i run the code it prints out :
4
4
5
8

sum = 8 which is right at that moment but the program stops calling itself after it hits a number thats not divisible by 2; i.e. 5.

I have tried adding another condition to have the code keep calling itself but no matter what i try i get a segmentation fault.

```
int digit = 0;
int sum = 0;

while (num > 0){
    digit = num%10;
    num /=10;
    break;
}
std::cout<<digit<<std::endl;

if (digit % 2 == 0){
sum += digit + rec_sum_even (num);
}
return sum ;
```

Comment: In the `while` loop, you never actually reduce `num`, so you will never hit the terminating condition.

Comment: There should be no loop, only recursion. It looks like you’ve started with a looping function and are now trying to restructure it into a recursive one. Start over instead. Write a function that sums all digits first, then add the condition.

Comment: If your recursive solution is stuck in an infinite loop, you've made an error. If it blows the call stack however, you're on the right track.

Comment: you have no end condition. Your function will call itself unconditionally. Think about that.

Comment: Going to start over again and give all of your suggestions a try. Thank you !

Comment: Also note that you never actually sum the even digits.

Comment: @Bob__ There's a `return X += recall` pattern. Though this example is demonstrably flawed, the pattern for unwind accumulation is present. In the presence of an infinite loop, the return semantics diminish in importance.

Comment: Sorry but you are just coding by trial & error without knowing what you are doing. That never works in programming. Step back and consider how this should work, with pen and paper, before writing any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are want a recursive function, it should check **single digit** not the entire number. Then you can recursively call this function for each digits. Note the *base case* of recursive function should return the *sum of 0 digits* i.e. **0**.

Here is a sample code:

```
unsigned int sum_even(unsigned int num){
 if(num == 0){
    return 0;
 }  
 int sum = 0;
 int last_digit = num % 10;
 if(last_digit % 2 == 0){
    sum += last_digit;
 }
 return sum + sum_even(num/10);
}
```

Comment: We might be able to do better -- if we change the `if` to instead read: `if (num % 2 == 0) { sum += num % 10; }` we do two modulus operations on even numbers, but only one on odd numbers.  Possibly eliminating some division operations vs. two modulus operations on *every* digit.

Comment: @cdlane Sure we can do that. Also we can reduce the code to just one mudulus operator by checking the even number using **bitwise &** operator. Like `if(!(last_digit&1)){
    sum += last_digit;
 }`

Comment: Just turn optimizations on: https://godbolt.org/z/5JNxCk